# How to use first data token in First Data global gateway e4?

Tags: wsdl, token, firstdata

I am using first data global gateway web service version 27. I am generating first data token from this site
https://developer.payeezy.com/payeezy-api/apis/post/transactions/tokens
Now i don't know where to use this token when request to web service? 
I am passing these parameters to web service

- ExactID
- Password
- Transaction_Type
- DollarAmount
- Expiry_Date
- CardHoldersName
- Card_Number
- TransarmorToken
- CardType

I use generated token in 'Card_Number' parameter but it gives me error 'Invalid credit card number'
Can someone please tell me where to use token?

Comment: did you ask in the payeezy forum?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same message, please check the CCN owner address.

- The CCN error validation disappeared after correction..

Hope this help!